# How to increase the vertical space surrounding mathematical equations?

Tags: spacing, equations, amsmath

How can I, in a systematic way, increase the vertical space
surrounding mathematical equations?

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[ansinew]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Ah, che bel vivere, che bel piacere, che bel piacere per un barbiere 
di qualità, di qualità! Ah, bravo Figaro! Bravo, bravissimo! Fortunatissimo
per verità! Pronto a far tutto, la notte e il giorno sempre d'intorno in giro sta.
\begin{equation}
\frac{(2n)!}{n!^{2}}=\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)} 
\end{equation}
Ah, che bel vivere, che bel piacere, che bel piacere per un barbiere 
di qualità, di qualità! Ah, bravo Figaro! Bravo, bravissimo! Fortunatissimo
per verità! Pronto a far tutto, la notte e il giorno sempre d'intorno in giro sta.
\vspace*{4pt}
\begin{equation}
\frac{(2n)!}{n!^{2}}=\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)} 
\end{equation}

\vspace*{4pt}
Ah, che bel vivere, che bel piacere, che bel piacere per un barbiere 
di qualità, di qualità! Ah, bravo Figaro! Bravo, bravissimo! Fortunatissimo
per verità! Pronto a far tutto, la notte e il giorno sempre d'intorno in giro sta.
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for featuring by far the best filler text I've seen in a long while in a TeX example.

Comment: For future reference, see `texdoc mathmode` section `11.5.1`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main variables are `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip`, but there are also some "short" versions for when the line preceding the display is no particularly long:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{\dimexpr\abovedisplayskip+10pt\relax}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{\dimexpr\abovedisplayshortskip+20pt\relax}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\dimexpr\belowdisplayskip+10pt\relax}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{\dimexpr\belowdisplayshortskip+10pt\relax}

Ah, che bel vivere, che bel piacere, che bel piacere per un barbiere 
di qualità, di qualità! Ah, bravo Figaro! Bravo, bravissimo! Fortunatissimo
per verità! Pronto a far tutto, la notte e il giorno sempre d'intorno in giro sta.
\begin{equation}
\frac{(2n)!}{n!^{2}}=\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)} 
\end{equation}
Ah, che bel vivere, che bel piacere, che bel piacere per un barbiere 
di qualità, di qualità! Ah, bravo Figaro! Bravo, bravissimo! Fortunatissimo
per verità! Pronto a far tutto, la notte e il giorno sempre d'intorno in giro sta.
\begin{equation}
\frac{(2n)!}{n!^{2}}=\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)} 
\end{equation}
Ah, che bel vivere, che bel piacere, che bel piacere per un barbiere 
di qualità, di qualità! Ah, bravo Figaro! Bravo, bravissimo! Fortunatissimo
per verità! Pronto a far tutto, la notte e il giorno sempre d'intorno
in giro sta.

Bravo.
\begin{equation}
\frac{(2n)!}{n!^{2}}=\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)} 
\end{equation}
Bravissimo.

\end{document}
```

As egreg points out these dimensions get reset when font size changing commands are issued.  So it probably best to adjust these in the definition of `\normalsize`.  Similar adjustments can be made for `\small` etc.  Here I use the suggestion of Mico to use `\addtolength` instead of `\setlength` for increase lengths and glues.  There is another mechanism available in the `memoir` class described below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\oldnormalsize\normalsize
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\oldnormalsize
\addtolength{\abovedisplayskip}{10pt}%
\addtolength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{20pt}%
\addtolength{\belowdisplayskip}{10pt}%
\addtolength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{10pt}%
}

\begin{document}

Ah, che bel vivere, che bel piacere, che bel piacere per un barbiere 
di qualità, di qualità! Ah, bravo Figaro! Bravo, bravissimo! Fortunatissimo
per verità! Pronto a far tutto, la notte e il giorno sempre d'intorno in giro sta.
\begin{equation}
\frac{(2n)!}{n!^{2}}=\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)} 
\end{equation}
Ah, che bel vivere, che bel piacere, che bel piacere per un barbiere 
di qualità, di qualità! Ah, bravo Figaro! Bravo, bravissimo! Fortunatissimo
per verità! Pronto a far tutto, la notte e il giorno sempre d'intorno in giro sta.
\begin{equation}
\frac{(2n)!}{n!^{2}}=\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)} 
\end{equation}
Ah, che bel vivere, che bel piacere, che bel piacere per un barbiere 
di qualità, di qualità! Ah, bravo Figaro! Bravo, bravissimo! Fortunatissimo
per verità! Pronto a far tutto, la notte e il giorno sempre d'intorno
in giro sta.

Bravo.
\begin{equation}
\frac{(2n)!}{n!^{2}}=\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)} 
\end{equation}
Bravissimo.

\small
Ah, che bel vivere, che bel piacere, che bel piacere per un barbiere 
di qualità, di qualità! Ah, bravo Figaro! Bravo, bravissimo! Fortunatissimo
per verità! Pronto a far tutto, la notte e il giorno sempre d'intorno in giro sta.
\begin{equation}
\frac{(2n)!}{n!^{2}}=\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)} 
\end{equation}
Ah, che bel vivere, che bel piacere, che bel piacere per un barbiere 
di qualità, di qualità! Ah, bravo Figaro! Bravo, bravissimo! Fortunatissimo
per verità! Pronto a far tutto, la notte e il giorno sempre d'intorno in giro sta.
\begin{equation}
\frac{(2n)!}{n!^{2}}=\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)} 
\end{equation}
Ah, che bel vivere, che bel piacere, che bel piacere per un barbiere 
di qualità, di qualità! Ah, bravo Figaro! Bravo, bravissimo! Fortunatissimo
per verità! Pronto a far tutto, la notte e il giorno sempre d'intorno
in giro sta.

Bravo.
\begin{equation}
\frac{(2n)!}{n!^{2}}=\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)} 
\end{equation}
Bravissimo.

\normalsize
Ah, che bel vivere, che bel piacere, che bel piacere per un barbiere 
di qualità, di qualità! Ah, bravo Figaro! Bravo, bravissimo! Fortunatissimo
per verità! Pronto a far tutto, la notte e il giorno sempre d'intorno in giro sta.
\begin{equation}
\frac{(2n)!}{n!^{2}}=\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)} 
\end{equation}
Ah, che bel vivere, che bel piacere, che bel piacere per un barbiere 
di qualità, di qualità! Ah, bravo Figaro! Bravo, bravissimo! Fortunatissimo
per verità! Pronto a far tutto, la notte e il giorno sempre d'intorno in giro sta.
\begin{equation}
\frac{(2n)!}{n!^{2}}=\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)} 
\end{equation}
Ah, che bel vivere, che bel piacere, che bel piacere per un barbiere 
di qualità, di qualità! Ah, bravo Figaro! Bravo, bravissimo! Fortunatissimo
per verità! Pronto a far tutto, la notte e il giorno sempre d'intorno
in giro sta.

Bravo.
\begin{equation}
\frac{(2n)!}{n!^{2}}=\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)} 
\end{equation}
Bravissimo.

\end{document}
```

The `memoir` class has an alternative approach if you want to scale these skips: to multiply the standard skips by `2.5` you can issue

```
\setDisplayskipStretch{2.5}
```

for example in the preamble.  For other types of adjust, it has a command `\memdskips` that by default is

```
\newcommand*{\memdskips}{% 
  \advance\abovedisplayskip \memdskipstretch\abovedisplayskip 
  \advance\belowdisplayskip \memdskipstretch\belowdisplayskip
  \advance\abovedisplayshortskip \memdskipstretch\abovedisplayshortskip
  \advance\belowdisplayshortskip \memdskipstretch\belowdisplayshortskip}
```

Thus to add `10pt` to most of these skips and `20pt` to the short above skip you can write:

```
\renewcommand*{\memdskips}{
  \addtolength{\abovedisplayskip}{10pt}%
  \addtolength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{20pt}%
  \addtolength{\belowdisplayskip}{10pt}%
  \addtolength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{10pt}}
```

Comment: The setting would be reverted to the default if one uses, say, `\small` outside of a group and then `\normalsize`.

Comment: The usage of `\usepackage` and `\RequirePackage` is mixed here.

Comment: @Mico Of course.  Now used in second version.

Comment: @egreg Indeed, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @PGFTricks Fixed to `\usepackage` for use in standard documents.

Comment: Magically this makes my thesis 25 pages longer! My prof will delighted what an hard-working student he has :)